# http in c# GET a page

Tags: http, c#-4.0

this is my for read a web page. in **c#** lang.
but it got some exceptions when I execute it.
any one know why ?

```
          try
        {
            string address = "http://" + txtMsg.Text;
            int port = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            System.Net.WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            String content = webclient.DownloadString(address);

            Socket skt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            skt.Connect(address, port);
            string hdrs = "GET " + address + ":" + port + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                + "Host: " + address + ":" + port + "\r\n";
            byte[] req_as_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hdrs);
            skt.Send(req_as_bytes);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 200];
            int t = skt.Receive(data);
            lstMsg.Items.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, t));
            skt.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            skt.Close();

            btnConnect.Text = "done";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: **What error do you get**? Did you read it?

Comment: this is the exception: "the requested name is valid but no data of requested type was found"

Comment: You're doing HTTP wrong.  Read the spec, and look at real requests in Fiddler, or (vastly preferable) use `WebClient` and let Microsoft do the work.

Comment: You're also doing socket-reading wrong; let's hope the response fits in a single packet..

Answer (score 3):

OK ! 
I found the solution:

```
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var address = "http://" + txtMsg.Text;
        var webclient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        var content = webclient.DownloadString(address);
        //any work 
        btnConnect.Text = "done";
    }
```